# Iterators using exceptions

Tags: java, exception

Hi my code is throwing an exception even though there is a character that can be returned. This is my code

```
/** Return true if there is another character for the instance to return. */
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if(cursor<characterSource.length()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;


    }

    /** Returns the next character in the String. */
    public Character next() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if(hasNext()) {
            int retVal=characterSource.indexOf(cursor);
            return characterSource.charAt(retVal);
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Besides not using `return cursor < cs.length()`, it looks like you're misusing `indexOf` and also not incrementing `cursor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `characterSource` is a `String` or something compatible, I think you should remove this line:

```
int retVal=characterSource.indexOf(cursor);
```

and adjust the other one:

```
return characterSource.charAt(cursor++);
```

Comment: While my answer gives you a solution about how to resolve your problem, here is what actually went wrong: You were calling `characterSource.indexOf(cursor)` which searches for the position of the character with the Unicode codepoint `cursor` (for example the NUL character if `cursor == 0`). There is a high chance that this will return `-1` and then the following `charAt` will throw an `IndexOfBoundsException`. This is probably not what you want. Just use `charAt` to retrieve the character at the position `cursor` and increment `cursor` afterwards. This is what my suggested fix does.

Comment: Huh? `indexOf` shouldn't be involved here at all.

Comment: @chrylis: Indeed, that's why my answer says that line should be removed :)

Comment: Sorry, I misread and have no idea why. I think I confused with your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this.

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return cursor < characterSource.length();
}

public Character next() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if(hasNext()) {
        return characterSource.charAt(cursor++);
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("End of string reached");
}
```

`cursor` already holds the index of the current character. There is no reason to call `characterSource.indexOf(cursor)`.